# Batch game map generator

Tags: batch-file

It says "set was unexpected at this time" the code:

```
@echo off
set x=5
set y=5
for /l %%x in (0,1,9) do (
    for /l %%y in (0,1,9) do (
        set /a map=%random% %% 5+1
        if %map% == 5 set m%%x%%y=#
        if not %map% == 5 set m%%x%%y=.
    )
)
```

The problem is here:

```
set /a map=%random% %% 5+1
if %map% == 5 set m%%x%%y=#
if not %map% == 5 set m%%x%%y=.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delayed expansion:

```
        @echo off
        set x=5
        set y=5
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        for /l %%x in (0,1,9) do (
            for /l %%y in (0,1,9) do (
                set /a map=!random! %% 5+1
                if !map! == 5 set m%%x%%y=#
                if not !map! == 5 set m%%x%%y=.
            )
        )
some other code here
    endlocal
```

More info here: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: You also need to use `!random!` instead of `%random%` if you want each iteration to get a different random number.

Comment: totally forgot about random!